# How does Lucene (Solr/ElasticSearch) so quickly do filtered term counts?

Tags: data-structures, solr, lucene, elasticsearch

From a data structure point of view how does Lucene (Solr/ElasticSearch) so quickly do filtered term counts? For example given all documents that contain the word "bacon" find the counts for all words in those documents.

First, for background, I understand that Lucene relies upon a compressed bit array data structure akin to [CONCISE](http://ricerca.mat.uniroma3.it/users/colanton/docs/concise.pdf). Conceptually this bit array holds a 0 for every document that doesn't match a term and a 1 for every document that does match a term. But the cool/awesome part is that this array can be highly compressed and is very fast at boolean operations. For example if you want to know which documents contain the terms "red" and "blue" then you grab the bit array corresponding to "red" and the bit array corresponding to "blue" and AND them together to get a bit array corresponding to matching documents.

But how then does Lucene quickly determine counts for all words in documents that match "bacon"? In my naive understanding, Lucene would have to take the bit array associated with bacon and AND it with the bit arrays for every single other word. Am I missing something? I don't understand how this can be efficient. Also, do these bit arrays have to be pulled off of disk? That sounds all the worse!

How's the magic work?

Comment: Could you link to the JavaDoc of the feature you're talking about? I'm looking up "filtered term counts" and coming up empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may already know this but it won't hurt to say that Lucene uses inverted indexing. In this indexing technique a dictionary of each word occurring in all documents is made and against each word information about that words occurrences is stored. Something like this image [image]

To achieve this Lucene stores documents, indexes and their Metadata in different files formats. Follow this link for file details `http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/fileformats.html#Overview`

If you read the `document numbers` section, each document is given an internal ID so when documents are found with word 'consign' the lucene engine has the reference to the metadata of it. 
Refer to the overview section to see what data gets saved in different lucene indexes. 
Now that we have a pointer to the stored documents Lucene may be getting it in one of the following ways

1. Really count the number of words if the document is stored
2. Use Term Dictionary, frequency, and proximity data to get the count.

Finally, which API are you using to "quickly determine counts for all words"

Image credit to http://leanjavaengineering.wordpress.com/

Check about index file format here http://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene80/package-summary.html#package.description

Comment: I don't know what this API is in Lucene itself, but in Solr or ElasticSearch I would do this using the facets. Basically I would run a query for "consign" and then do a facet count for all tokens that exists *only in documents that contain consign*.

Answer (score 2):

there are no bitsets involved: its an inverted index. Each term maps to a list of documents. In lucene the algorithms work on iterators of these "lists", so items from the iterator are read on-demand, not all at once.

this diagram shows a very simple conjunction algorithm that just uses a next() operation: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/processing-boolean-queries-1.html

Behind the scenes, it is much like this diagram in lucene. Our lists are delta-encoded and bitpacked, and augmented with a skiplist which allows us to intersect more efficiently (via the additional advance() operation) than the above algorithm though.

DocIDSetIterator is this "enumerator" in lucene. it has the two main methods, next() and advance(). And yes, it is true you can decide to read the entire list + convert it into a bitset in memory, and implement this iterator over that in-memory bitset. This is what happens if you use CachingWrapperFilter.

Comment: So given the listOfDocIdsThatMatchQuery and for a given docIdList in the invertedIndex, count how many times we can docIdList.Advance(id) for each id in listOfDocIdsThatMatchQuery before running off of the end of the skiplist. Whatever that count is is the value for the facet for that term. Sound about right?

Comment: Does all of this stay in RAM? Or are we pulling something off of disk? I wonder what happens when the corpus is large enough to no longer fit in memory.

Comment: pages are in RAM if your operating system caches it :) Its essentially like a BufferedInputStream: we read blocks of 128 documents at a time, with any remainder compressed one-doc-at-a-time. you can also seek to a later part of the stream with skiplist data (its block-aligned, so we dont build skiplists if a term is rare and has < 128 postings).